# In ASP.NET MVC + Telerik MVC Grid ,How would I show a PDF/ Doc /Text File, in a PopUP window instead of allowing users to download it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, popupwindow

How would I show a PDF/ Doc /Text File, in a PopUP window instead of allowing users to download it ?

These files path is stored in a database table and in my ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Project I have a folder named " Files" where my actual files are stored .

I have a Telerik MVC Grid where there is a column named AssociatedFiles and in this column there is a ClientTemplate such as " View File ". Once someone clicks on this Link , actual file associated with that RowID should be displayed in a PopUP instead of allowing users to download it .

Using FilePathResult I can allow my users to download it but I dont want this . I want users to view that perticular File in a PopUp Window .

I searched alot for the associated code for this perticular scenario but couldnt find anything usefull . Please Help me with actual working codes. Send your comments @ ashes22@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a partial View to your View Folder named " FilePopUp" . Here use Telerik Window Control

Code :-

```
 <% Html.Telerik().Window()
            .Name("PopupWindow")
            //.Title("View PDF")
            //.Icon(Url.Content("~/Content/Common/Icons/favicon.png"), "favicon")
            .LoadContentFrom(Model.PDFFilePath).Modal(true)
            .Buttons(buttons => buttons.Close(Url.Action("Controller", "Action")))
            //.Buttons(buttons => buttons.Maximize(Url.Action("Controller")).Close(Url.Action("Controller", "Action")))
            .Scrollable(false)
            .Resizable()
            .Draggable(true)
            .Width(870)
            .Height(500)
            .Render();
    %>
```

In your Controller :-

```
            public ActionResult GetPdffile(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            FilePathAdmin filePath = new FilePathAdmin();
            filePath.ERAPDFFilePath = this.WorkerService.GetPdfFilepath(id);
           //string filepath = this.WorkerService.GetPdfFilepath(ID);
            return PartialView("PopUpWindow", filePath);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bool reThrow = ExceptionPolicyWrapper.HandleException(ex, ExceptionPolicies.MVCPolicy);
            if (reThrow)
                throw;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In your Model Class , create another Class named " FilePathAdmin" and write following code in it

```
           public class FilePathAdmin
{
    public string ERAPDFFilePath { get; set; }
}
```

And thats it .. You are done